# C# Structs "this = ...."

Tags: c#, struct

I've just been browsing a file in reflector and seen this in a struct constructor:

```
this = new Binder.SyntaxNodeOrToken();
```

I've not seen that terminology before. Can someone explain what that this assignment means in C#. It's difficult to Google.

Comment: Unless I'm crazy that is an error.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Either we're both crazy or I agree. Perhaps reflector goofed?

Comment: @ChaosPandion this is completely legal for `struct` in C#

Comment: @JaredPar - Now I thought I knew everything about C#... Of course I did knew I was crazy.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It replaces the value, basically. It effectively copies all the fields from the right side to the left... except it works even if the fields are readonly. And yes, it *does* look distinctly weird, and it's somewhat scary.

Example:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Point point = new Point(10, 20);
        point.ReplaceWith(new Point(2, 3));
        Console.WriteLine(point); // (2, 3)
    }
}

struct Point
{
    private readonly int x;
    private readonly int y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void ReplaceWith(Point other)
    {
        this = other;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("({0}, {1})", x, y);
    }
}
```

For more information, read section 7.6.7 of the C# 4 spec, which includes:

> - [text about its use in a struct constructor]
> - When `this` is used in a *primary-expression* within an instance method or instance accessor of a struct, it is classified as a variable. The type of the variable is the instance type of the struct within which the usage occurs.
>
>   - If the method or accessor is not an iterator, the `this` variable represents the struct for which the method or accessor was invoked, and behaves exactly the same as a `ref` parameter of the struct type.
>   - [text about iterators]

Comment: This is so weird ... C# is overwhelming my (maybe many others too) programming concept

Comment: @ziq: Don't forget that `this` is "the whole value" in a value type, not a reference. I think that's the critical part.

Comment: How can it be performed ? Replacing oneself while a member function is running ( in this example ReplaceWith

Comment: @ziq: Would you be surprised by just setting each field individually? Think of it in exactly the same way. Imagine that each instance method is prefaced with a parameter `ref this`...

Comment: Thanks Jon for the explanation.

Comment: Being able to modify the values of readonly fields *really* bothers me (then again, I guess I can understand how it works internally, considering how structs differ from classes)

Comment: @luiscubal: Or, as [Eric Lippert explains it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two.aspx), "`readonly` fields in a struct are the moral equivalent of the struct author writing a cheque without having the funds to back it."

Comment: @DanielPryden: Part of why I prefer structs with exposed public fields.  If a struct is held in a storage location that is never in future going to be exposed to anything that's going to write it, its fields will be immutable, whether or not the struct exposes them.  If it's held in a storage location that will be written, all field--public and private--will be mutable, regardless of how they're declared.  While private struct fields can be useful for some purposes, making fields private for the purpose of making alterations cumbersome without adding any invariants is silly.

Comment: @DanielPryden [new link](https://ericlippert.com/2011/05/31/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-two/)

Answer (score 6):

If `s1` and `s2` are structs of type `Foo`, with fields `f1`, `f2`, and `f3`, the statement `s1 = s2` is semantically equivalent to

```
s1.f1 = s2.f1;
s1.f2 = s2.f2;
s1.f3 = s2.f3;
```

except that one should make no assumption about the order of the assignment operations (or even the relative ordering of reads and writes; the generated code might, for example, read all three fields into registers, and then write all three fields).  All fields will be copied, independent of whether they are public or private, mutable or so-called immutable.  No property getters or setters will be called; neither the source nor destination struct will receive any notice that the fields of the structs are being duplicated or overwritten.

A statement `this = new Foo(whatever);` is in C#(*) equivalent to

```
Foo temp;
call Foo's constructor (out temp, whatever);
this.f1 = temp.f1;
this.f2 = temp.f2;
this.f3 = temp.f3;
```

(*) Struct constructor semantics in vb.net are different

As above, the field assignments are done without regard for whether the fields are public or private, and without regard for whether they are supposedly immutable.

One reason I believe (contrary to the view of some other people) that structs should often expose mutable fields is that syntax like:

```
// Assume myKVP is a field of type KeyValuePair<Wizzle, int>
rr = new KeyValuePair<Wizzle, int>(myKVP.Key, myKVP.Value + 1);
```

makes it appear as though `myKVP` will refer to a different instance after the assignment from what it held before, when what is actually happening is:

```
// Assumes backing fields are named _Key and _Value
// Note that C# won't allow one to write private fields directly, but the
// act of copying one struct instance to another copies all the fields,
// public and private, from the source instance to the destination.
KeyValuePair<Wizzle, int> temp;
temp._Key = myKVP.Key; // Constructor has access to backing fields
temp._Value = myKVP.Value+1;
myKVP._Key = temp._Key; // Struct assignment copies all fields, public and private
myKVP.Value = temp.Value;
```

In other words, the statement does not make `myKVP` report to a different instance; instead, it creates a new instance, *mutates* the old instance by overwriting its fields with those of the new instance, and then discards the new instance.  If some code was evaluating `myKVP.ToString()` while the above assignment took place, the mutation would affect the instance of `myMVP` that was being printed.

Structs can have useful semantics, but so-called "immutable" structs aren't.  Non-trivial structs (those for which it's possible to create a value different from the default) are mutable if and only if they are kept in mutable *storage locations*, regardless of any semantics imposed by the type.  Self-mutating structs, i.e. structs which mutate `this` in any methods except in constructors and property setters, can have some unexpected behaviors because compilers have no way of forbidding the invocation of other methods which will mutate `this` on immutable struct *instances*.  Public exposure of struct fields, however, does not pose any such danger.  Since all fields of a mutable instance of a non-trivial struct are inherently mutable, regardless of any attempts the struct might make to allow mutation, and all fields of an immutable instance of a struct are immutable even if they're exposed, a struct which endeavors to make its fields "immutable" is really telling a lie.  A lie which may at times be useful (e.g. if field contents are supposed to obey certain invariants) but which shouldn't be told without some real cause.

Comment: I don't follow your argument.  Your `myKVP` syntax example is confusing and doesn't seem to follow C# grammar.  If a struct is intended to be immutable, then why would it contain "other methods which will mutate `this`"?  And there seems to be some confusion in your last paragraph about the difference between a *value type* and the *instances* of that type.  Could you edit your answer to better explain what you're trying to say?

Comment: @DanielPryden: I just added  a couple more comments and tried to clarify the latter paragraph.  The original question was why one <i>can</i> replace `this` with another struct.  The reason one can do that is that one isn't really replacing `this`; one is merely replacing the contents of all its fields with those of the other structure.  I then wanted to say that the fact that one <i>can</i> mutate "this", whether by overwriting the whole thing or altering its fields, doesn't mean one should.