# Go "this"-keyword

Tags: go

After diving into the docs I couldn't find the answer to my following question:

Is there any reason against using `this` for referring to the current object as in the following example?

```
type MyStruct struct {
  someField string
}

func (this MyStruct) getSomeField() string {
  return this.someField
}
```

Comment: It's not idiomatic in Go. In Python you also use `self` rather than `this` or any other name because it's idiomatic.

Comment: `this`, `self`, `me`, etc have never been descriptive or good identifiers and have always been a bad idea. If you're stuck in a language that requires you use one of them you have no choice. Go isn't such a language so use something descriptive and reasonable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no *technical* reason not to do this.

It does go against the general guidelines as explained [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments):

> Don't use generic names such as "me", "this" or "self", identifiers typical of object-oriented languages that place more emphasis on methods as opposed to functions.

I would also like to add that in languages that use `this` (or `self`), `this` is always a *pointer*. For method receivers in Go, this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: What would be a good, non-generic, name to use in function definitions? In `func (p Person) Foo()`, `p` doesn't really seem any more descriptive than `this`.

Comment: Genericity and descriptivity (?) are not the same. `p` is a non-generic choice, but *in itself* it is not very description. Its descriptiveness comes from the combination with its type.

Comment: I agree with 425nesp. The name of the variable is used to describe in one word the meaning of the value it holds. If it didn't, we could be using memory addresses instead. So the type doesn't really add any descriptiveness.

Comment: `this` is not always a pointer: in C#, `this` for struct methods stands for struct value rather than a pointer to it. E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648939/c-sharp-structs-this