# Go, Why shouldn't use "this" for method receiver name

Tags: reflection, go, visual-studio-code

I use VS Code Go extension.

Here's my code

```
func (this *MyClass) Xxx() error {}
```

And It's mention me this

> exported method `MyClass.Xxx` should have comment or be unexported
>
> receiver name should be a reflection of its identity; don't use generic names such as "`me`", "`this`", or "`self`";

Comment: Hi this question was answered: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/286406/use-of-this-in-golang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028512/go-this-keywordh

Comment: In short words: The `this` means `inheritance`. `Inheritance` means `abstract` and `virtual` methods. That is, with the `Inheritance` you can write `this.callAbstractMethod()`. Go language does not support `inheritance`. This means that `receiver` is not a `this` because `this` always means something that maybe not a `this` but an `other` (eg. `super`). In Go language there are no `super` instances under the `this` instance since in Go language not exists inheritance as such.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/3qoo36/question_why_is_self_or_this_not_considered_a/)

> `v.Method()` is actually syntactic sugar and Go also understands the de-sugared version of it: `(T).Method(v)`. [You can see an example here](http://play.golang.org/p/YKI1HGqeM7).

```
package main

type T struct{}

func (t T) Method() {}

func main() {
    t := T{}
    t.Method()    // this is valid
    (T).Method(t) // this too
}
```

> **Naming the receiver like any other parameter reflects that it is, in fact, just another parameter quite well**.

As [Ixrec](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/161917/ixrec) puts it in [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/286409/3915):

> In other languages the `this`/`self`/`whatever` variable typically has some special properties such as being magically provided by the language, or having special access to private methods (remember Go doesn't have private fields/methods).
>   Though the "receiver" is still being "magically provided" to some extent, it's so similar to a regular function argument it arguably doesn't count.

Comment: See also https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names