# What advantage is there to storing "this" in a local variable in a struct method?

Tags: c#, .net

I was browsing the .NET Core source tree today and ran across [this pattern](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1dc118cc46f88e4889a23190b450d89e565967fd/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray%601.cs#L134-L143) in `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<T>`:

```cs
T IList<T>.this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        var self = this;
        self.ThrowInvalidOperationIfNotInitialized();
        return self[index];
    }
    set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
}
```

This pattern (storing `this` in a local variable) seems to be consistently applied in this file whenever `this` would otherwise be referenced multiple times in the same method, but not when it is only referenced once. So I started thinking about what the relative advantages might be to doing it this way; it seems to me that the advantage is likely performance-related, so I went down this route a little further... maybe I'm overlooking something else.

The [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) that gets emitted for the "store `this` in a local" pattern seems to look something like a `ldarg.0`, then `ldobj UnderlyingType`, then `stloc.0` so that later references come from `ldloc.0` instead of a bare `ldarg.0` like it would be to just use `this` multiple times.

Maybe `ldarg.0` is significantly slower than `ldloc.0`, but not by enough for either the C#-to-CIL translation or the JITter to look for opportunities to optimize this for us, such that it makes more sense to write this weird-looking pattern in C# code any time we would otherwise emit two `ldarg.0` instructions in a struct instance method?

*Update: or, you know, I could have looked at the comments at the top of that file, which [explain](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1dc118cc46f88e4889a23190b450d89e565967fd/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray%601.cs#L18-L33) exactly what's going on...*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As you already noticed, System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<T> is a **struct**:

```
public partial struct ImmutableArray<T> : ...
{
    ...

    T IList<T>.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            var self = this;
            self.ThrowInvalidOperationIfNotInitialized();
            return self[index];
        }
        set { throw new NotSupportedException(); }
    }

    ...
```

`var self = this;` creates a copy of the struct referred to by *this*. Why should it need to do that? The [source comments of this struct](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1dc118cc46f88e4889a23190b450d89e565967fd/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray%601.cs#L18-L33) give an explanation of why it is necessary:

> /// This type should be thread-safe. As a struct, it cannot protect its
>   own fields
>   /// from being changed from one thread while its members are executing on other threads
>   /// because structs can change *in place* simply by reassigning the field containing
>   /// this struct. Therefore it is extremely important that
>   /// ** Every member should only dereference this ONCE. **
>   /// If a member needs to reference the array field, that counts as a dereference of this.
>   /// Calling other instance members (properties or methods) also counts as dereferencing this.
>   /// Any member that needs to use this more than once must instead
>   /// assign this to a local variable and use that for the rest of the code instead.
>   /// This effectively copies the one field in the struct to a local variable so that
>   /// it is insulated from other threads.

In short, if it is possible that other threads are making changes to a field of the struct or changing the struct in place (by reassigning a class member field of this struct type, for example) while the get method is being executed and thus could cause bad side effects, then it becomes necessary for the get method to first make a (local) copy of the struct before processing it.

Update: Please also read [supercats answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30958421/2819245), which explains in detail which conditions must be fulfilled so that an operation like making a local copy of a struct (i.e. `var self = this;`) is being thread-safe, and what could happen if those conditions are not met.

Comment: Hmm, but considering that `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray<T>` is immutable, if that's the only consideration, then isn't this pattern simply a way to burn a few more CPU cycles than otherwise?

Comment: Now I am curious. if you look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648939/c-sharp-structs-this then why is it possible to set `this = ...` if calling `this` creates a new instance of the struct?

Comment: @Benj, what do you mean with "calling this"? Note that a struct is a value type, thus an assignment "=" copies the struct...

Comment: @JoeAmenta, read the source code comments for that data type ("*This type should be thread-safe. As a struct, it cannot protect its own fields from being changed from one thread while its members are executing on other threads because structs can change 'in place' simply by reassigning the field containing this struct.*"). Also note, that the class you were looking at was not perhaps always immutable (assuming it is indeed immutable which it does not seem to be according to the source comments) and the code you are seeing is just a "left-over" from an older revision... who knows...

Comment: @JoeAmenta, done, and i just noticed that the source comments actually contain a rather exhaustive explanation. When i wrote my last comment, i was just skimming over the source code comments without taking a closer look :)

Comment: @elgonzo it's actually more like L18-33 https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/1dc118cc46f88e4889a23190b450d89e565967fd/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableArray%601.cs#L18-L33 (I've also edited the question to have this link as well which is why I deleted the comment you're replying to)

Comment: @JoeAmenta, neat trick with this link. Didn't know that this is possible (i just copied the link from your question without looking at it). I'll update the link in my answer. But i will also keep the quote in the answer ( it took me so much work to include it :p) so people can read it without needing to follow the link...

Comment: @Xanatos, why not... Make a class which is having a field that is of a struct type and then let two threads access struct members of this field at the same time...

Comment: @elgonzo The point is that even an immutable `struct` could be not-thread safe, because the whole `struct` could be changed in-place.

Comment: @elgonzo Simple example to show it: http://ideone.com/fDnKz9, and the "correct" version using the suggestion of the source code: http://ideone.com/tbYeX6

Comment: @elgonzo I'll add that it is probably a recent discovery of this problem by Microsoft... I'm looking at [`DateTime.ToLocalTime()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,5f39b12e679532c6,references) and it isn't thread safe... This would be quite puzzling for a programmer if he had any problem there... The same for [`Nullable.Value`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,7b38d1fa76071c95,references)

Comment: @xanatos, it can get even funnier. Guess the output of this example: http://ideone.com/PuCFuc (Note that s2 is a readonly field, whereas s1 is not). One really has to be careful with structs.

Comment: @elgonzo That is known (or at least I did know :-) )... Accessing methods of a readonly field of a struct causes the method to be called on a copy of the struct. See [Jon Skeet's blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/07/16/micro-optimization-the-surprising-inefficiency-of-readonly-fields/)

Comment: @xanatos, while structs are value types s it has (to my knowledge) never been claimed that operations on them are atomic. Hence it would be false to assume that operations on structs would be thread-safe per-se. I could also not find any information with regard to MS claiming DateTime.ToLocalTime() or Nullable.Value being thread-safe...

Comment: @elgonzo *after* knowing what happens it is clear and it is logical. **after**! While there are many articles about multithreading, I haven't ever read anything about this.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer - author of code in question :)
@xanatos brings up an interesting point that DateTime is not as thread safe as `ImmutableArray<T>`, despite the DateTime documentation [which claims it is thread-safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime(v=vs.110).aspx). I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2119) to track this.

Comment: This is not thread-safe under ECMA. There is nothing in ECMA that prevents the JIT from deleting that assignment. It is a valid single-threaded optimization and ECMA makes extremely weak guarantees regarding multi-threaded unsynchronized access.

Answer (score 10):

Structure instances in .NET are always mutable if the underlying storage location is mutable, and always immutable if the underlying storage location is immutable.  It's possible for structure types to "pretend" to be immutable, but .NET will allow structure-type instances to be modified by anything that can write the storage locations in which they reside, and the structure types themselves have no say in the matter.

Thus, if one had a struct:

```
struct foo {
  String x;
  override String ToString() {
    String result = x;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return result & "+" & x;
  }
  foo(String xx) { x = xx; }
}
```

and one were to invoke the following method on two threads with the same array `myFoos` of type `foo[]`:

```
myFoos[0] = new foo(DateTime.Now.ToString());
var st = myFoos[0].ToString();
```

it would be entirely possible that whichever thread started first would have its `ToString()` value report the time written by its constructor call and the time reported by the other thread's constructor call, rather than reporting the same string twice.  For methods whose purpose is to validate a structure field and then use it, having the field change between the validation and the use would result in the method using an unvalidated field.  Copying the contents of the structure's field (either by copying just the field, or by copying the whole structure) avoids that danger.

Note that for structures which contain a field of type `Int64`, `UInt64`, or `Double`, or which contain more than one field, it is possible that a statement like `var temp=this;` which occurs in one thread while another thread is overwriting the location where `this` had been stored, may end up copying a structure which holds an arbitrary mixture of old and new content.  Only when a structure contains a single field of a reference type, or a single field of a 32-bit-or-smaller primitive, is it guaranteed that a read that occurs simultaneous with a write will yield some value that the structure actually held, and even that may have some quirks (e.g. at least in VB.NET, a statement like `someField = New foo("george")` may clear `someField` before calling the constructor).

Comment: *Structure instances in .NET are always mutable if the underlying storage location is mutable, and always immutable if the underlying storage location is immutable.* Sometimes things should be written in characters of fire in the sky, so that anyone can read them. Today is the first time I've discovered that an immutable `struct` could be not-thread safe... If I think enough it is clear... `int64` can be subject to tearing (high and low part are modified not-at-the-same-time) if multiple threads read and write it at the same time... so it is clear that any `struct` could be subject to it.

Comment: @xanatos: A structure which contains a single field of reference type, or a single field of a "short" primitive type, will be immune to tearing.  In many cases where it is necessary to wrap a single reference to an immutable instance of a mutable type, a struct may offer better performance and better semantics than a class [e.g. if `BigInteger` were a struct with a single field of type `int[]` (using the first few items of the array to hold things like cached hash value, etc.) then it would be possible for `default(BigInteger)` to behave as the value zero, rather than as a null reference.]

Comment: Yep... the tearing is an intersecting class of problems to the one we are speaking about here... Still it is strange that, in the end, you can't even be sure that `int.GetHashcode()` is thread safe or not... (it is, because it is simply `return this`) but `short.GetHashCode` probably isn't, because it is: `return (int)((ushort)this) | (int)this << 16;`

Comment: I wonder why `short.GetHashCode` would be written like that rather than as `unchecked(this*65537)` [or better yet, some other value]?  I can't think of cases where thread safety would matter on `GetHashCode` (rewriting a structure would invalidate any knowledge one has about its hash code anyway) but the fact that calling `GetHashCode` on a short could potentially yield a value not associated with any `short` value would seem odd.

Comment: All good points, @supercat. But I would add that there *is* a way to read an Int64 in a thread-safe way. Using [Interlocked.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read(v=vs.110).aspx) for example.

Comment: @AndrewArnott: Use of an interlocked read will only provide thread-safety *with regard to interlocked writes*.  It will not provide thread safety with regard to "ordinary" rights.  A mutable struct which holds an `Int64` can be written to allow thread-safe reads and writes, provided that nobody tries to copy a struct while another thread is copying over it.  Such thread-safety cannot be achieved with an "immutable" struct, because the only way to change its contents will be to use a non-interlocked structure copy operation.

Comment: @AndrewArnott: I wish C# had been written to use one token for class field access and member function calls with `this` passed by value, and a different token for struct field access and member function calls with `this` passed as `ref`, so that calls to struct methods which mutate `this` would be more conspicuous, and would only be allowed in cases where they would actually be useful; being able to have some class members accept `this` as a `ref` would also be useful for things like delegates (so e.g. `someDelegate.:Combine(otherDelegate)` would be a thread-safe way of combining delegates).