# How set initial state of object, without 'this' assignment

Tags: c#

I have a class with the property `Capacity`, when `Capacity = 0`, object must sets in initial state. I do this with method `InitState()`, because I can't create a new instance and assignment to `this`. Is there way use `this` or another way to set initial state?

```
public class Test {
  private int _field1 = -1;
  private int[] _array;
  ...

  public Test() : this(0) { }      

  public Test(int capacity) {
    _array = new int[capacity];
  }
  ...
  public int Capacity {
    get { return _array.Length; }
    set
    {
      //not working 
      //if(value == 0) this = new Test();
      if(value == 0) InitState();
      ...
    }
  }

  //sets fields in default state
  private void InitState() {
    _field1 = -1;
    _array = new int[0];
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: By use `this` do you mean your default constructor called `Test()`?  Why do you need to create a new instance of the object?

Comment: You are on the right track even though you think its the wrong one. Your `InitState` should take a capacity and initialize the object. Call the same `InitState(capacity)` from the constructor. You can't assign a value to the `this` pointer as you found out.

Comment: Calling the init method again is wasteful, instead call `Array.Clear` on `_array`.

Comment: If you change your class to a struct, [then you can use `this = ` notation to replace the current instance][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9648939/c-sharp-structs-this

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't assign a value to this so you're code is correct